# When will be OAuth 2.0 shutdown?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

Google is shutting down OAuth 1.0 on 20 April 2015.
My project was previously using oauth 1.0, So I have updated code and used OAuth 2.0

Now I want to know when OAuth 2.0 will be shutdown. I came across the url [Using OAuth 2.0 for Login (early version)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2LoginV1)

Which saying the "Google has deprecated the early implementation of OAuth 2.0", So did they end up current OAuth 2.0 version?

Comment: OK really good question.    What I get from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable is that they haven't set a date for shutting down the first version of oauth2.   I can see if I can track down someone at Google That may know a better 100% anwser

Comment: yup, i would like to know this as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OAuth can be used for authentication (knowing who the user is), and authorization (accessing data on behalf of the user).

The open standard for doing *authentication* with OAuth 2.0 is [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect), which Google supports.  The old document titled "OAuth 2.0 for Login (Early version)" referred to an earlier recommendation for how to authenticate users using OAuth 2.0, before OpenID Connect existed.  So the only thing deprecated in that doc was this old authentication pattern, in favor of the final, standardized implementation of OpenID Connect.  As long as you use OAuth 2.0, and OpenID Connect – you're fine.

In short, it is safe to use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to access data on behalf of users, and the final version of [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) to authenticate users.  The industry is standardizing around these two protocols, and you should be safe using them for some time to come.  You can read a [recent announcement](http://openid.net/2015/04/17/openid-connect-certification-program/) by the OpenID Foundation that included Google as one of the leading proponents of OpenID Connect (and OpenID Connect depends on OAuth 2.0).